# Sudo su is not picking up the password

Tags: command-line, sudo, password, root

When I type command like `sudo su`,`su` or `sudo -i`, I get the space to enter the password. But the problem is when I type the password it is not entered in the terminal. I tried pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> then typing the password but no help. In GUI based password dialogs (like unlocking Ubuntu while booting) it is working fine. Is there any alternative for a root access terminal in Ubuntu LTS 18.04.3?

Comment: Passwords are not echoed back. This is by design, and goes back many many many years. (That is, `sudo -i` prints `Password:` and waits for you to enter the password. You type your password and press Enter. You won't see anything on the terminal. *After* you have typed the password and pressed Enter, `sudo` will either execute a root shell and you will see the `#` prompt, or else `sudo` will complain about a wrong password. But while typing the password you won't have any feedback.)